# getText() retorna null ao tentar ler o valor de digitado em um EditText

Tags: java, android

Tenho um campo de EditText e quero salvar o Texto nele contido ao apertar um botao
eu tentei faze-lo usando o seguinte codigo porem a string permanece como null

```
    public void Botao (View view) {
      setContentView(R.layout.content_main_menu);


      EditText valor = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ValorEdit);
      String ValorF = valor.getText().toString()
```

Aparentemente o programa só esta recebendo o estado anterior do EditText e não o texto digitado.

Answer (score 3):

É porque você está setando um novo `layout`. Remova `setContentView(R.layout.content_main_menu);`

Comment: funcionou muito obrigado.